# IOS app crash with this title pb_enc_bool

Tags: ios, firebase, crash

App crash multiple times with the below error on firebase:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  Medcura                        0x10cf94 pb_enc_bool + 140 (pb_encode.c:140)
1  Medcura                        0x10c830 pb_encode + 544 (pb_encode.c:544)
2  Medcura                        0x134404 FIRSESEncodeProto + 60 (FIRSESNanoPBHelpers.m:60)
3  Medcura                        0x145f58 SessionStartEvent.transportBytes() + 155 (SessionStartEvent.swift:155)
4  Medcura                        0x1461e0 @objc SessionStartEvent.transportBytes() + 4329972192 (<compiler-generated>:4329972192)
5  Medcura                        0xfe1c0 -[GDTCOREvent setDataObject:] + 89 (GDTCOREvent.m:89)
6  Medcura                        0x13f3f8 EventGDTLogger.logEvent(event:completion:) + 44 (EventGDTLogger.swift:44)
7  Medcura                        0x13f4f4 protocol witness for EventGDTLoggerProtocol.logEvent(event:completion:) in conformance EventGDTLogger + 4329944308 (<compiler-generated>:4329944308)
8  Medcura                        0x145264 closure #1 in SessionCoordinator.attemptLoggingSessionStart(event:callback:) + 47 (SessionCoordinator.swift:47)
9  Medcura                        0x145464 closure #1 in SessionCoordinator.fillInFIID(event:callback:) + 77 (SessionCoordinator.swift:77)
10 Medcura                        0x144070 partial apply for closure #1 in FIRInstallations.installationID(completion:) + 30 (Installations+InstallationsProtocol.swift:30)
11 Medcura                        0x143f34 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed String?, @guaranteed Error?) -> () + 4329963316 (<compiler-generated>:4329963316)
12 Medcura                        0xe5928 __49-[FIRInstallations installationIDWithCompletion:]_block_invoke + 201 (FIRInstallations.m:201)
13 Medcura                        0xdd0b4 __56-[FBLPromise chainOnQueue:chainedFulfill:chainedReject:]_block_invoke.33 + 273 (FBLPromise.m:273)
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x1cb8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x3910 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x11ff0 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 1056
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x11bc0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44
18 CoreFoundation                 0xbeecc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
19 CoreFoundation                 0x7c7d0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1996
20 CoreFoundation                 0x7b9ac CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
21 HIToolbox                      0x30448 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
22 HIToolbox                      0x30284 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 648
23 HIToolbox                      0x2ffdc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 76
24 AppKit                         0x398a4 _DPSNextEvent + 660
25 AppKit                         0x813980 -[NSApplication(NSEventRouting) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 716
26 AppKit                         0x2cd50 -[NSApplication run] + 476
27 AppKit                         0x4014 NSApplicationMain + 880
28 AppKit                         0x2573a4 _NSApplicationMainWithInfoDictionary + 22
29 UIKitMacHelper                 0x46a8 UINSApplicationMain + 972
30 UIKitCore                      0x3cfc UIApplicationMain + 148
31 UIKitCore                      0x2ce12c __swift_destroy_boxed_opaque_existential_1Tm + 12220
32 Medcura                        0x95f98 main + 4329250712 (AppDelegate.swift:4329250712)
33 ???                            0x1845950e0 (Missing)
```

I have tried to delete firebase SDK from the app and install it again, but nothing will work.